# Huge differences between webmaster tools' crawl stats and apache logs

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

We noticed huge difference in the metrics. For example, last saturday :

- According to Webmaster Tools :

  - 6,082 pages crawled
  - 76,119 kilobytes downloaded
  - 1,550 ms in average to download a page
- Now according to our apache logs, grepping "Googlebot" :

  - 1,444 pages crawled (2,997 including all our subdomains : blog, images, tracking, ...)
  - 201 ms on average (we use apache logs' "%D" to monitor this, which is the time to last byte)

We are not on the same timezone so the results may vary, but the trend is the same everyday : 2 to 3 times more pages crawled on Webmaster Tools, and 5x to 10x more time to download the pages. And it's similar on other domains, too.

I can't find any explaination about this. Are there other useragents we need to monitor ? 
What else ?

Comment: The full list is here - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en and the one you want to look out for is most likely mobile, desktop and image.